# Find downloaded video files via coursera app

Tags: downloading, file-management

There is a possibility to download and play videos via coursera android app. But I want to play the downloaded video with my desired video player in my android device. where is the downloaded video file saved? In other words, how can I find the video file with my file manager and in which directory it's been saved?

Answer (score 8):

You can copy the videos from this app's location in `/data/data/org.coursera.android/files/courkitDownloadedVideos/` if your device is rooted. It could instead be found at: `storage/extSdCard/Android/data/org.coursera.android/files/Download/` if you have an external SD card.

On an un-rooted device, you can use `adb backup` function to backup the app and its data to a file on your computer, and then extract its contents:

1. Install and Android SDK and USB drivers for your device.
2. In Windows open Command Prompt (or Terminal in Linux), navigate to a directory where you want to store the backup, and issue the following command: `adb backup -f courseraBackup.ab org.coursera.android` This backs up the app and its data (including the downloaded videos) to your computer's C drive.
3. Convert the backup to an archive using command `dd if=courseraBackup.ab bs=24 skip=1|openssl zlib -d > courseraBackup.tar`

   - If you use Linux, then just issue the above command in Terminal.
   - On Windows, it's a tad more complicated since you have to download and install Cygwin from [here](http://cygwin.com/install.html) (install all packages,) and then use the Cygwin Terminal to run the above command.
4. Extract the archive either using `tar xvf courseraBackup.tar` (in Terminal for Linux of Cygwin in Windows,) or using your favorite archival tool (e.g. 7-Zip.)

You should now have a directory on your computer containing all the data from the app, including any downloaded videos.

Refer: http://nelenkov.blogspot.ca/2012/06/unpacking-android-backups.html

Answer (score 7):

The app downloads the videos to /data/data/org.coursera.android/files/courkitDownloadedVideos/ instead of the standard user space of /sdcard/Android/data/* and even worse yet, the files are named file2.mp4 file3.mp4 etc. making it difficult to figure out which file is which course. I personally find this very frustrating as I would love to stream the videos to my XBMC box using Yatse.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no _/org.coursera.android/_ in _/data/data_ .

Comment: @Amir you need to be rooted in order to view items in `/data/data/` directory. It would look empty on an un-rooted system.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an app called, coursera on the go that lets you choose the location of download matterial, (move to external sdcard for example) and also labels the files like a sane person would do.
[http://www.amazon.com/Aliaksei-Radzinski-Coursera-On-The/dp/B00COJ2KTE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00COJ2KTE)

Comment: Coursera on the Go seems to have gone away. I cannot find it anywhere.