# How to transfer videos downloaded via coursera app from my tablet to my computer?

Tags: backup, debug

I tried using the answer here:
[Find downloaded video files via coursera app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66628/find-downloaded-video-files-via-coursera-app)
but to no avail.

My device is unrooted and hence the data folder is hidden.
I tried the method suggested by Naveen as well in the question whose link I provided above but my system(I am running Windows 8) does not recognize my tab(lenovo b6000) to be connected to the system. I turned on the developer mode in my tab and also enabled backup and reset, but it was still not recognized by the computer.

Please suggest a safe way to move the videos I have downloaded via the coursera app in my tablet to my PC(Running Windows8 with adb installed).

Thank you.

Comment: You could try to `adb backup` the app, and then investigate the backup file (see: [Is there a way to look inside and modify an adb backup created file?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/23357/16575)). If that doesn't work out (devs can opt-out their apps from ADB backup), the only solution left is to root the device.

Comment: See also this related question: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/66628/26477.